# Javascript. The calc() function does not work as soon as i add the math.floor function

Tags: javascript

the function works properly when instead of math.floor(math.random() * 10 + 1); i use math.random(). why does adding math.floor stop the program from working?

```
    for(x=0; x< 5; x++){

    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 +1) ;
    var b = math.floor(Math.random() *10 +1) ;
    var c = math.floor(Math.random() *10 +1) ;
    var d = math.floor(Math.random() *10 +1) ; 

        document.write((a*b)/(c*d)+"<br>") ;
```

Comment: Isn't this just a case issue ? (math instead of Math)

Answer (score 3):

You are using lowercase `math` instead of TitleCase `Math`.

```
for(x=0; x< 5; x++){
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 +1) ;
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() *10 +1) ;
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() *10 +1) ;
    var d = Math.floor(Math.random() *10 +1) ; 
}
document.write((a*b)/(c*d)+"<br>") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `M` in `Math` has to be uppercase, as in your first variable assignment:

```
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1) ;
```